Google Play Store App PlayCore SDK needs updating. How to go about it?
my app is in the Google Play store but i recently received notice that my SDK is outdated. I'm new to app development as well as to the play store so I'm not sure what the process is to update it. Can anyone give some advice?
The app was uploaded as a .aab file.
The instruction is to update any existing import statements of Task Objects from import com.google.android.play.core.tasks.* to import com.google.android.gms.tasks.*
Additionally, to remove any imports of the old Play Core libraries in my build.gradle file.
I am lost as to how to address this issue...
On the PlayCore web page (developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration), there is a description of steps to integrate libraries, as well as the codes, but I don't know whether I should be using my original .aab file or if there is a way to download the modified file from the play store.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Follow this steps: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration

You should edit your apps source code, remove the implementation "play:core" and put the new implementation in the build.gradle and change the imports you already mentioned!
Then again generate signed Bundle of your app and upload it.
Greetz

Thanks Greetz. I realize why I was having so many problems... The 3rd party that packaged my app as an .aab file locked the build.gradle on their server so that I can't do the edit without them. Sadge... I'm going to have to figure out how to build a new version of my app for the play store.

@SekayiLiburd oh that sucks, maybe you can get the source code from them?
